# compiling QT 5.10.0 on linux (ubuntu) - complain about not finding qmake configuration file

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, compilation, installation

I am trying to build QT from source on linux machine (ubuntu 18) using g++ x86_64 arch.

When I run the ./configure script, I get the below result:

```
# ./configure -prefix ../qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0 -release -opensource nomake -tests

cd qtbase

/home/qt-easy-build/qt-easy-build/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/configure -top-level -prefix ../qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0 -release -opensource nomake -tests

Creating qmake...

.Done.

**Could not find qmake configuration file .**

Error processing project file: /home/qt-easy-build/qt-easy-build/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0
```

Does anyone know which and where qmake configuration file/s is missing?

Comment: The `prefix` is weird, it seems to point to the second folder. Did you try with another versions of Qt? Also you really shouldn't use 5.10.0. You should be using 5.11.2 (latest release) or 5.9.7 (latest LTS release). If you really need to have a 5.10, use 5.10.1, it is binary compatible with 5.10.0.

Comment: 1. It is `-nomake tests`, your dash is at the wrong place
2. `-top-level` is an internal flag. Do not use it unless you know what your doing
3. The prefix seems weird. Use an absolute filepath that does **not** point to or inside the source folder. You can also leave it out completly to create an uninstalled build, just to see if it helps

Comment: Thanks. I was using  [jcfr/qt-easy-build](https://github.com/jcfr/qt-easy-build/tree/5.11.2) as a shortcut to simplify the process thinking their script downloads anyway the same QT sources but apparently something was broken there. Once I switched to use the formal QT sources repo and build procedure the issue disappeared.